# openshift commands to catch POD name programmatically/scripting

Tags: shell, awk, grep, openshift

I have pods in my open shift and want to work on multiple open shift applications. Lets say like below

sh-4.2$ oc get pods

```
NAME                                  READY     STATUS      RESTARTS   AGE
jenkins-7fb689fc66-fs2xb              1/1       Running     0          4d
jenkins-disk-check-1587834000         0/1       Completed   0          21h

NAME                                 READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
jenkins-7fb689fc66-gsz9j              0/1       Running   735        9d
jenkins-disk-check-1587834000    

NAME                                READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
jenkins-9euygc66-gsz9j               0/1       Running   735        9d
```

I have tried with below command

oc get pods

```
export POD=$(oc get pods | awk '{print $1}' | grep jenkins*)
```

I want to find the pods starting with numbers "jenkins-7fb689fc66-fs2xb",jenkins-9euygc66-gsz9j, etc... using scripting and need to ignore disk check pods. If i catch the above pods and need to execute the terminal and run some shell commands via programmatically. Can someone help me on this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`kubectl get` (and by extension `oc get`) is a *very* versatile tool. Unfortunately, after looking around online for awhile, you will *definitely* not be able to do Regex without relying on an external tool like `awk` or `grep`. (I know this wasn't *exactly* what you were asking, but I figured I'd at least try to see if it's possible.

With that said, there are a couple of tricks you can rely on to filter your `oc get` output before you even have to pull in external tools (bonus points because this filtering occurs on the server before it even hits your local tools).

I *first* recommend running `oc get pods --show-labels`, because if the pods you need are appropriately labeled, you can use a label selector to get just the pods you want, e.g.:

```
oc get pods --selector name=jenkins
oc get pods --selector <label_key>=<label_value>
```

*Second*, if you only care about the `Running` pods (since the `disk-check` pods look like they're already `Completed`), you can use a field selector, e.g.:

```
oc get pods --field-selector status.phase=Running
oc get pods --field-selector <json_path>=<json_value>
```

*Finally*, if there's a *specific* value that you're after, you can pull that value into the CLI by specifying custom columns, and then `grep`ing on the value you care about, e.g.:

```
oc get pods -o custom-columns=NAME:.metadata.name,TYPES:.status.conditions[*].type | grep "Ready"
```

The best thing is, if you rely on the label selector and/or field selector, the filtering occurs server side to cut down on the data that ends up making it to your final custom columns, making everything that much more efficient.

---

For your *specific* use case, it appears that simply using the `--field-selector` would be enough, since the `disk-check` pods are already `Completed`. So, without further information on *exactly* how the Jenkins pod's JSON is constructed, this should be good enough for you:

```
oc get pods --field-selector status.phase=Running
```

Comment: Hi Will, Thanks a lot for your explanation. oc get pods --field-selector status.phase=Running command is more enough to catch the POD name. Thanks a lot for the brief explanation

Comment: Hi @Will Gordon, I used to run the command you posted and it is working manually but unfortunately it is not giving exact value from my script call.                            NAME                                  READY     STATUS      RESTARTS   AGE
jenkins-7fb689fc66-fs2xb              1/1       Running     0          5d
jenkins-disk-check-1587920400-2z9vw   0/1       Completed   0          14h
Error: unknown flag: --field-selector

Comment: I ran this command : POD=`oc get pods --field-selector status.phase=Running | awk '{print $1}' | grep jenkins-*` Do i need to add anything here?

Comment: "Unknown flag" is usually a version issue. What are you seeing from `oc version`?

Comment: I got this info : (sh-4.2$ oc version
oc v3.11.0-alpha.0+1ff2229-9
kubernetes v1.10.0+b81c8f8
features: Basic-Auth GSSAPI Kerberos SPNEG). I see this commad will work after 3.9 version as per knowledge . This command works perfectly in OC Application Terminal but somehow calling from script is failing

Comment: Hi could you update your question with the output from 2 different commands (it formats better if you put it in the question). 1) `oc get pods --field-selector status.phase=Running` and 2) `oc get pods --field-selector status.phase=Running -o custom-columns=NAME:.metadata.name | grep jenkins-*`.

Comment: `sh-4.2$ oc get pods --field-selector status.phase=Running -o custom-columns=NAME:.metadata.name | grep jenkins-*
jenkins-7fb689fc66-fs2xb`
`sh-4.2$ oc get pods --field-selector status.phase=Running
NAME                       READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
jenkins-7fb689fc66-fs2xb   1/1       Running   0          5d`

Comment: 2) command gives exact output but problem is getting Error: unknown flag: --field-selector while i trigger this script from Jenkins jobs.

Comment: So the second command is working _as expected_, but you're _still_ seeing an error message?! So weird, you _could_ just ignore error output by running `oc get pods --field-selector status.phase=Running -o custom-columns=NAME:.metadata.name 2>/dev/null | grep jenkins-*`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you need to print jenkins id in first field, could you please try following.

```
awk 'match($0,/jenkins[^ ]*/){print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)}' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding explanation for above code.

```
awk '                                ##Starting awk program from here.
match($0,/jenkins[^ ]*/){            ##Using match function in which mentioning regex jenkins till spacein current line.
  print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)    ##Printing sub-string in current line where starting point is RSTART till RLENGTH value.
}
' Input_file                         ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Comment: But i need to print the  jenkins-7fb689fc66-fs2xb  value and to ignore the disk check value of the pods

Comment: @KandikuppaVinod, I didn't get it, could you please explain more on this one, what is not working?

Comment: I need to get the only value like jenkins-7fb689fc66-fs2xb  and need to grab thae value and keep it in ${POD} variable.and should not print jenkins-disk-check-1587920400-2z9vw value.

Comment: @KandikuppaVinod, I am still not sure if I get it, how about this `awk 'match($0,/jenkins-7fb689fc66[^ ]*/){print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)}'  Input_file` try this once?

Comment: Thanks, But one thing which i want to fetch that jenkins-7fb689fc66 value dynamically without passing 7fb689fc66  I mean the value "jenkins-<starts with number> " always want to find and get that string. (Ex : `awk '{print $1}' | grep jenkins-*` ) - O/p: jenkins-7fb689fc66

Answer (score 0):

Adding this answer for others reference.
You could use in this way.

```
export POD=$(oc get pods | awk '{print $1}' | grep jenkins* | grep -v jenkins-disk-check)
```