# Bash script to check if openshift/kubernetes pods are ready

Tags: bash, kubernetes, while-loop, openshift, until-loop

I am trying to create a shell script that will validate that certain pods are ready by checking the READY heading showing 1/1. I have tried two ways.

1.

```
ready=$(oc get pods | awk '{print $2}' | tail -n +2) # prints 1/1 or 0/1 for each pod
until [[ ${ready} == "1/1" ]]
do
  echo "Waiting for pods to be ready."
  sleep 3
done
```

Above script just keeps saying "Waiting for pods to be ready" even when the pods are ready and displaying 1/1 in the READY column.

2.

```
while true ; do
  for i in 1 2 3; do
  ready=`oc get pods | awk '{print $2}' | tail -n +2 | head -n $i` 

  if [[ "${ready}" == "1/1" ]]; then
    echo "pods are up and running"
  else
    echo "waiting for pods to be ready"
  sleep 10
  break
  fi
  done
done
```

Above script just continually prints waiting for pods to be ready and pods are up and running.

Any help would be appreciated, I am starting with Bash and not quite sure what to do.

Comment: why do you need the scripts? Are you using pod directly, or its sub resources of deployment? Using pod directly is not recommended. If you have a deployment, did you try `oc rollout status` ?

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/61446220/6758654. You really shouldn't be relying on `1/1`, there are more and better ways to determine exactly what pods are ready.

Comment: @C Han, we use scripts to deploy our apps sort of like Helm as we don't yet have Helm.

Comment: I am trying another option to poll the readiness and here is what I did.
`status=$(oc get pods -o jsonpath='{.items[*].status.containerStatuses[?(@.ready)].ready}')

 for stat in $(oc get pods -o jsonpath='{.items[*].status.containerStatuses[?(@.ready)].ready}'); do

   until [[ "${stat}" == "true" ]]; do

     echo "waiting for pods to be ready"
     sleep 10
   done
done
echo "pods are ready"`

Answer (score 11):

I'm surprised no one so far has mentioned the experimental, yet official [kubectl wait](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#wait):
`$ kubectl wait ([-f FILENAME] | resource.group/resource.name | resource.group [(-l label | --all)]) [--for=delete|--for condition=available]`

Comment: This answer should be way on top! `kubectl -n mynamespace wait pod --for=condition=Ready -l labelKey1=labelValue1,labelKey2=labelValue2`

Comment: After my initial excitement on this response: this condition will wait ONLY if the pod exists (i.e. managed to be created). In my script, after `helm install` pod still needs some time to appear hence the command fails with `Error from server (NotFound): pods "proc-s1e2-0" not found`

Comment: I suppose this was resolved by the time, but for anyone wondering there is a wait flag on helm install command.

Comment: Command to wait for pod to be in "Ready" state with a timeout of 60 seconds: `kubectl wait --for=condition=Ready pod/<name-of-the-pod> --timeout=60s -n <name-of-the-namespace>`

1. If the pod is ready within the timeout period (60 seconds), it will exit with return code **0** and outputs a message `pod/<name-of-the-pod> condition met`

2. If the pod is **not** ready even after 60 seconds, timeout occurs and it will exit with return code **1** and outputs a message `error: timed out waiting for the condition on pod/<name-of-the-pod>`

Answer (score 6):

Following solutions works for me

```
while [ "$(kubectl get pods -l=app='activemq' -o jsonpath='{.items[*].status.containerStatuses[0].ready}')" != "true" ]; do
   sleep 5
   echo "Waiting for Broker to be ready."
done
```

Answer (score 4):

For pod status, the one and only answer (a pod can be Running but not yet ready!):

```
kubectl get pods -l <key=val> -o 'jsonpath={..status.conditions[?(@.type=="Ready")].status}'
```

For individual container statuses (need to be "true"):

```
kubectl get pod <pod_name> --output="jsonpath={.status.containerStatuses[*].ready}" | cut -d' ' -f2
```

If you want to check the status of several pods, you can use -l to filter and just prefix `.items[*]`:

```
kubectl get pods -l <key=val> --output="jsonpath={.items[*].status.conditions[*].status}"
```